# Excel 2010 filter arrow not showing text values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an odd problem on a tracker spreadsheet I use. All the columns have a filter, but when you click on the filter arrow it doesn't show you a breakdown of all the text values for that column. All it shows is the usual 'sort A to Z/Z to A', but the bottom half of the pop-up screen is blank, where normally you have a list of text values that you can further filter by putting a tick next to each.

It only displays (Select All) which you can tick, but its pointless as the column has selected all text values and hasn't been further filtered, which is what I need to do.

Comment: When you say "the bottom half of the pop-up screen is blank", do you mean there are check boxes without values next to them or do you mean the list ends before it should?

Comment: No values, no check boxes apart from (Select All), nothing underneath it.

Comment: Just saw this happen yesterday to a friend. Sometimes this can be caused by another filter on another column that is filtering out what you are looking for. Check the other filters. Hope it's that simple.

Comment: Aha! I've found what was causing it, and yes you were right it was another filter which i didnt even notice! Appreciate your help CharlieRB!!

Comment: Sure thing. I will add it as an answer. If you would be so kind to choose it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this happen yesterday to a friend. Sometimes this can be caused by another filter on another column that is filtering out what you are looking for. Check the other filters. Hope it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason the filter must have been applied to only one row. Since top row values are considered as headers, there are no other values to be displayed.

The solution is to select the whole table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.